# Failure to install packages after setting yarn to package manager

Tags: npm, angular-cli, yarnpkg

Im trying to setup a new project with angular cli and have set my package manger like this:

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

However, when I try to create a new angular project with cli, I get this

```
Installing packages for tooling via yarn.
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

So then I start looking to see if I have yarn even installed and I do this:

```
 D:\devsrc>npm list -g --depth=0
```

and get this:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@1.3.1
+-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
`-- typescript@2.2.2

npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^5.0.1, required by @angular/core@2.4.10
npm ERR! extraneous: tsickle@0.2.5 C:\Users\
```

How can I have 2 different versions of angular cli installed?
How can I clean this up and get Yarn installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing, you are getting `'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error is because you do not have `yarn` globally installed run 
`npm install yarn -g` to fix that

Second you have two `@angular/cli@1.3.1` and `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3` packages is because the `angular cli` package name has being changed since version `1.0.0-beta.28.3`. Before it was `angular-cli` now it is `@angular/cli` so just uninstall the old one `uninstall angular-cli -g`. After that you might need to reinstall the latest one `npm install @angular/cli -g`